# Difference between URL and Loader on Vector Source - OpenLayers 3

Tags: vector, openlayers-3

I have to load a  WFS layer from my Geoserver to my website with Openlayers 3.9.0.

According to [the manual](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html) there are two options to load features, `loader`([ol.FeatureLoader](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/apidoc/ol.html#.FeatureLoader)) and `url` ([ol.FeatureUrlFunction](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/apidoc/ol.html#.FeatureUrlFunction)).

I dont get the difference between the two. They both used to load features, `loader`, does not set any URL and looks more complicated.

I tried:

```js
    var url =  'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/mapname/wfs?service=WFS&'+'version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=mapname:awesomelayer&'+'outputFormat=application/json&maxFeatures=50'    
    var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
              format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
              loader: function(extent){
                    $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type:'GET',
                    dataType: 'jsonp'
                    }).done(loadFeatures);
               },
              strategy: new ol.loadingstrategy.tile(ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({maxZoom: 20}))
    });
    
    var loadFeatures = function(response) {
      var features = vectorSource.readFeatures(response);
      vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
    };
```

...and no errors at all, but also no features.

Then I simply set:

```js
    var url =  'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/mapname/wfs?service=WFS&'+'version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=mapname:awesomelayer&'+'outputFormat=application/json&maxFeatures=50'    
    var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
              format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
              strategy: new ol.loadingstrategy.tile(ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({maxZoom: 20})),
              url: function(extent, resolution, projection){return url}
    });
```

....which worked.

I do not get the difference, `url` is similar, quicker and does not require a `loadFeatures` function. I read the manual, but in practice, in terms of code, I cannot understand  it. What is `loader` for, why it does not set a URL and when to use it? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

The first reason that comes to mind: to catch errors.  If your server is able to catch errors and return them inside the response, you might want to read them inside your loader and act accordingly.

A second reason would be to compute/execute some operations before those features are added to the source. Here's an [example in an other thread from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093482/is-it-possible-to-add-a-icon-symbol-to-a-polygon/27251137#27251137).  It features both these reasons to use a loader.

If you do not need to do anything special with your data before it's being added or if you do not need to manage errors, then `url` is enough for your requirements, indeed.

Comment: OK, makes sense now. By the way, any ideas on why the loader version does not work? Thanks again

Comment: Hi.  If you could create a JSFiddle, I'd be happy to help into looking what's wrong.

Comment: Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/slevin/cn8jsdmz/1/) out. I dont know why it does not work. I use `jQuery 1.11.3` not `1.11.0`. If I replace `http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs` with `http://localhost:3000/geoserver/mymap/wfs` it does not work even though I see no errors. `wfs GET` has status `200 OK`. I dont get it, it looks fine to me, I can spot the bug. Any tip would be great. Thank you

Comment: My code is based on [this](http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/b4xtz3cf/). I also uses Openlayers 3.9.0

Comment: The query works fine, however there seems to be something wrong with the reading of the geometry.  See you updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/cn8jsdmz/3/  This would be something not related to this thread, so I suggest you start a new one if you can't figure the issue out.

Answer (score 2):

Mybe this will work better

```
var url =  'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/mapname/wfs?service=WFS&'+'version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=mapname:awesomelayer&'+'outputFormat=application/json&maxFeatures=50'    
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
          format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
          loader: function(extent, resolution, projection){
                $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type:'GET',
                dataType: 'jsonp'
                }).done(function(response) {

                    var features = vectorSource.readFeatures(response, {
                        featureProjection: projection
                    });

                    vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
                });
           },
          strategy: new ol.loadingstrategy.tile(ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({maxZoom: 20}))
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the same problem as yours. Method with `url` works well, but I faced problem when using the `Loader`.

Here's the problem, from your `url` I notice that your `outputFormat=application/json`, meanwhile inside the `loader function` you specified `dataType: 'jsonp'` .

The `dataType: 'jsonp'` only works if your `outputFormat=text/javascript` . Refer to this [link by GeoServer](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/outputformats.html) , it explains format with its correct syntax.

Therefore you have to use JSONP instead of JSON, in order to enable JSONP please follow the answer in here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57494/geoserver-2-3-how-to-enable-jsonp . After that change your `outputFormat` to `outputFormat=text/javascript`